# Using synthesized mutator vs. assignment

Tags: objective-c

In my program, I am assigning a value to a property in the init method. I later use this property in response to an event.

Given a property named Object; **why** does the synthesized setter `[self setObject:obj]` work, but `Object = obj` give an Invalid Selector exception? Is it because the mutator adds one to the reference count on obj?

**Edit:** Here is more code, to give context. When I say "work" above, I mean run without errors.

Here is the initialization of the object(A View Controller) which has the property in it:

**Note:** All properties are declared as `(nonatomic, retain)`.

```
@synthesize _Kiosk;

....

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andKiosk: (Kiosk*) kiosk
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self set_Kiosk:kiosk]; //This work witout error. _kiosk = kiosk Fails at point below.
    }
    return self;
}

....

- (IBAction) ActionPressed:(id)sender
{
    [_CompanyName setText: [_Kiosk _CompanyName]];  //Failure happens here
}
```

And here is the method call that initializes this View Controller:

```
@synthesize _Kiosk;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:true withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    _Kiosk = [[Kiosk alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = [_KioskViewController initWithNibName:@"iPadKioskView" bundle:nil andKiosk: _Kiosk];

    [_Kiosk release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what is happening here. Could you post some code, e.g. showing the ivars, the property declaration, the initialisation of the class and the code that accesses the Object property?

Comment: FWIW, what do you mean with "work"? What invalid selector?

Comment: Thanks for your time! I added more context. And when I say work, I meant runs without error, (does not get the Invalid Selector error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@property` basically just declares two methods: `setFoo:` and `foo`. `@synthesize` will create the method bodies for those methods, which will correctly retain the new value and release the old one.

Assigning directly to the instance variable, however, doesn't call those accessor methods. It just makes the pointer point to a new object. If you're going to manually set the instance variable, then you need to make sure to correctly retain new value and release the old one.

Note that `[self setFoo:someFoo]` and `self.foo = someFoo` will both call the accessor method, while `foo = someFoo` just sets the instance variable directly, bypassing your setter method.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code gave the answer. You set _Kiosk already, so don't release it. There is no need to assign _Kiosk in the initWithNibName:etc. anymore. Just release the Kiosk in the dealloc method. If you want to change the Kiosk, use `class.Kiosk =` so the property is invoked, which is bound to retain it and release the previous kiosk.

Answer (score 0):

You definitively have to retain your kiosk parameter in the [init..] method. Otherwise it will be released, and you get an error soon or later.

One way is to do it yourself by calling retain on it, or you can use a synthetized setter, if it is defined as (nonatomic, **retain**).

Comment: Perhaps I should have included that in BOTH places I have the `_Kiosk` property, it is declared in the header file as `@property (nonatomic, retain)`.

Comment: If you want the "automated generated" setter to be called : use the dot notation as : self._kiosk = kiosk